# Add Image Comment Excel 16 on Mac osx

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I need your help! I've read many many forum and tread, but unfortunately I don't find a solution.

I'll need to build a macro that working on excel for Mac that pick an image from url and insert in a comment.

Thanks in advance

Here is a macro that working well on windows, but not in Mac osx.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim pic_file As String
    Dim pict1 As Picture
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set rngToCheck = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(n + 1, 2))
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
       ' pic_file = "http://xxx.xxx.com" & CStr(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value) & ".jpg"

        pic_file = "http://xxx.xxx.com" & CStr(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value) & ".jpg"


        Set pict1 = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic_file)
        If Not pict1 Is Nothing Then On Error Resume Next
            If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then ActiveCell.AddComment
                With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape
                   .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
                   .Fill.UserPicture (pic_file)
                   If (pict1.Width < pict1.Height) Then
                     .Height = 200
                     .Width = pict1.Width / pict1.Height * 200
                   Else
                     .Width = 200
                     .Height = pict1.Height / pict1.Width * 200
                   End If
                End With
            ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
            'ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
            pict1.Delete

            'Selection.Delete
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.EnableEvents = True
      '  End If
    End If


End Sub
```

In widows all works fine, in Mac I've only the empty yellow comment boxes.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`  this line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see the errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work. • Remove it and fix your errors. Also see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Hi @pᴇʜ, thank for your fast reply! without 'on error next' the reply is error runtime 91 Object variable not set, but i think to set all object properly :(

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ line 14 'ActiveCell.Comment.Delete' , for what I read the problem for the Mac is ' ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert' , but is impossible for me find a alternative solution.

Comment: The error means that there is no comment in `ActiveCell` that could be deleted. Replace the line with `If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then ActiveCell.Comment.Delete` so it is only deleted if it exists. • Note that `On Error Resume Next` is twice in your code. You need to remove both of them.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think that the first  ['on error resume next'] is separate to the error on line 14 or in other words is necessary to run the macro, sorry for my poor English, and the second is relatively to the pic string. Like this the code produce no error but only yellow empty boxes (on Mac, on windows work well and all images are in the comment box), if I cut ['on error resume next'] I've the problem that I solved in the past, and the macro stop working in windows and Mac version of excel

Comment: No already 1 `On Error Resume Next` hides **all** error messages until `End Sub`. It does not only hide the next error as the "next" might indicate. It reads more like "**From now on** if any error occurs just continue with the *next* code line". Therefore using `On Error Resume Next` like you did is a very bad practice (check out the link in the first comment for further information). • If you use it like you did, it tells VBA "In any case of an error, please don't tell anyone that the code failed". So that means if your code fails you will not even notice that it failed.

Comment: Thank for perfect example, now I understand. so, if I remove both `On error resume next` I've an error on line 24 `.Fill.Visible = msoTrue` but I've very short practice in via to understand what the error mean

Comment: so, I've really need an help, can anyone share a contact of freelance vba developer?

Comment: And which error? I mean if we always have to ask for the same information again and again we cannot really help you. We can only help you if you tell us **what** is going wong, we always need to know which code throws the error and what was the error message. And please [edit] and update the code to what you actually tested right now.